# Not getting authenticated using AzureTokenServiceProvider

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to use a Managed Service Identity for an App Service in Azure with my ASP.NET Core 3.0 WebApp.
So for the local development I want to have seamless integration. As [documented by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication) I tried to use the VS Developer Account to be authenticated and configured this one, as this did not work I installed the Azure CLI, authenticated and made sure that there is a token returned using `az account get-access-token`.

When debugging (directly dotnet, not using IIS Express) it always shows that I am not authenticated. (`_tokenProvider.PrincipalUsed` is always `null` and obviously the KeyVault Secret request fails due to this).

Comment: Can you please check the claims generated in Token via `AzureTokenServiceProvider`? There is another method `GetAccessTokenAsync` and using that you can generate the token.

Comment: So could you get the token successfully with `GetAccessTokenAsync` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, try to log out your account in the VS and log in again.

Also make sure your user account is in the `Access policies` of your keyvault in the portal with correct permission.

Then try the code below to get the secret.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var azureServiceTokenProvider1 = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var kv = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider1.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
            var secret = kv.GetSecretAsync("https://<keyvault-name>.vault.azure.net/", "<secret-name>").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine(secret);
        }
```

Comment: The key issue was to make sure at least one token was requested before checking the property ```PrincipalUsed```.